# Hidden Powershell Sheduled Task

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I'm Running a Gaming PC and I wrote a Wallpaper Switching script in Powershell because Windows 11 doesn't allow me to set a Wallpaper Slideshow with the same Picture on Every Monitor. The Skript would be called on User login and every 30 Minutes after that indefinitely.
The Skript looks like this (WIP - First the Problem described here needs to be fixe)

```
# Path of my slideshow
$wallpaperPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyPictures")+"\Wallpaper\Slide"
# Select random File from path
$wallpaperFile = Get-ChildItem -name -Path $wallpaperPath | Select-Object -index $(Get-Random $((Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaperPath).Count))
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\" -name wallpaper -value $wallpaperPath\$wallpaperFile
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

I'm Trying to Run this Script with Task Scheduler. For Convenience Purposes the Task need to run as the Logged in User. (Without Admin Rights, no stored credentials are needed to give access to the Pictures Folder of the User which is needed in the Powershell Skript)
But every time the Task Scheduler Runs the Skript, there is a Window that Pops up, gains Fokes while doing so, and disappears again. Due to this, any Game will minimise every time the Skript runs.
I've tried to Run the Task with these commands and Parameters:

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -command "C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"
```

After that, I discovered a VB Script Wrapper everywhere on the net in different variations but the same in the core. It promises to create a Windowsless Powershell instance which would execute the Skript without ever creating a Windows.
The VB Skript looks like this:

```
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -command ""C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"""
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command, 0, False
```

And the Task would then Execute this VB Script which would then run the Skript Windows less:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow_hidden.vbs"
```

At first, it seems like this helped. I tried executing the Scheduled Task manually a few times and I saw now windows popping up, like the other times. But after Rebooting and Running a Game during an automatically started Task Run I quickly learned that if the Task Runs automatically there is still a Windows Popping up.

So I tried another approach. I found a Git Repo: https://github.com/SeidChr/RunHiddenConsole
This Executable has the exact same Promises as the VB Skript, but it is programmed in C++ and has been compiled into a single .exe.
Renaming that exe to powershellw.exe and placing it next to the powershell.exe and then calling powershellw.exe instead of powershell.exe in Task Scheduler or other Apps should start a Windowless instance of powershellw.exe which forwards anything windowless to powershell.exe.
So everything would look like this:

```
powershellw.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -command "C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"
```

But it has exactly the same effect as the VB Skript. At manual execution, there is no Window. At automatic Execution, a Windows is throwing me out of the Game.

So I even tried to Combine different approaches by Using powershellw.exe the will be executed from a VB Script without a Windows.
That would look like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.vbs
```

```
command = "powershellw.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -command ""C:\Users\User\Git\Code\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"""
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command, 0, False
```

But I never got it Working. Still, a Windows that is throwing me out of the Game on automatic Tash Scheduler Execution.
The Last Approach I tried is to Use "Run whether a user is logged on or not" in the Task Scheduler instead of Running when a specific User Logged in. This got indeed rid of the Windows Popping up. Unfortunately, it also gets rid of any Functionality. I assume it Runs with a different User Context that way, so the Users Pictures Folder either can't be accessed or the Environment is Different and it's looking for Pictures in a completely different Users Profile.

###### So is there any really working way on Windows 11 to run a Scheduled Task that will run a Powershell  Script completely unnoticeable for the User in the Users User Context and Environment?

## Update 19.06.2023 11am:

as Discussed in the comments i now tried a few additional thing.

First there is a Inline Powershell Script that compiles a Windows application Powershell Host without any Window. https://www-mariotti-de.translate.goog/simpler-powershell-host-zum-ausfuehren-von-powershell-skripten-ohne-stoerendes-konsolenfenster/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp
I entered the path of PowerShellHost.exe in the scheduled task settings and the path to the PowerShell script as an argument.

This is an example .xml Task Sheduler Export:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2023-06-16T15:28:33.3784615</Date>
    <Author>User</Author>
    <URI>\Eigene\Wallpaper Slideshow</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT30M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>User</UserId>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>UserID</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Git\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\PowerShellHost.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>"C:\Git\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow_Task.ps1"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Second i don't want to start the Script once by System startup and keep it in the background so there is no new process, because it takes up resources and it could be unreliable.

> You can reproduce mentioned behavior with my provided code examples and creating an sheduled task as described in my post. Then Reboot, Log-in, Run a Exclusiv fullscreen Game and let it sit there until the task gets executed automatically. You'll notice that the game will minimize on every automatic execution. Even using the Compiled PowerShellHost.exe or other Compiled Windowsless/Hidden Console Hosts or forwarders or the aforementioned VB Script. Alternativly you can just use this Website and Watch the Log while you have Fokused the Browser and the automitcly started Task sheduler task Runns. [http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~cc248/jsphylosvg/js/yui/tests/event/tests/manual/window-focus-test.html](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Ecc248/jsphylosvg/js/yui/tests/event/tests/manual/window-focus-test.html)

## Update 19.06.2023 8pm:

I now identifyed exactly what windows is Popping Up and i Refined the Powershell Skript itself.
Here is the new Skript

```
# Path of my slideshow
$wallpaper_path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyPictures") + "\Wallpaper\Slide"
# Select random File from path
$new_wallpaper_file_obj = Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaper_path | Get-Random
$new_wallpaper_file_path = $new_wallpaper_file_obj.DirectoryName + "\" + $new_wallpaper_file_obj.Name

# Get currently set Wallpaper File
$TIC = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' TranscodedImageCache -ErrorAction Stop).TranscodedImageCache
$current_wallpaper_file_path = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($TIC) -replace '(.+)([A-Z]:[0-9a-zA-Z\\])+', '$2'

# Check if New Wallpaper isn't the same as the current one, Repeat Random Until this Condition is met.
while ($current_wallpaper_file_path -eq $new_wallpaper_file_path) {
    $new_wallpaper_file_obj = Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaper_path | Get-Random
    $new_wallpaper_file_path = $new_wallpaper_file_obj.DirectoryName + "\" + $new_wallpaper_file_obj.Name
}

# Define New Wallpaper Type to set new Wallpaper with
$setwallpapersrc = @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Wallpaper
{
    public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
    public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
    public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
    public static void SetWallpaper(string path)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange);
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $setwallpapersrc

# Set New Wallpaper
[Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($new_wallpaper_file_path)
```

But still the same Windows Pops Up still even using all the hidden Console Hosts and stuff.
This is what i know so far about that Pop Up:

[image: Watch Monitor provided by zett42]

[image: Task Sheduler Log]

[image: Fokus Logs of the afforementioned Fokus Test Website]

The Powershell Watrch Monitor zett42 Provided:

```
# Windows PowerShell (5.1) script
# Watch top-level window creation and log window name, process ID and process name.

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies UIAutomationClient, UIAutomationTypes -TypeDef @'
using System;
using System.Windows.Automation;

public class WindowWatcher
{
    public static void Watch()
    {
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
            WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
            TreeScope.Children,
            (sender, e) => {
                var element = sender as AutomationElement;
                var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById( element.Current.ProcessId );
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Window Title: {0}, ProcessId: {1}, ProcessName: {2}", element.Current.Name, element.Current.ProcessId, process.ProcessName ));
            });

        Console.ReadLine();
        Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
    }
}
'@

[WindowWatcher]::Watch()
```

Comment: You could create a custom PowerShell host using a C# script compiled as a Windows application instead of a console application. It's very little code and can even be compiled as an EXE using only PowerShell, as this example shows: https://www-mariotti-de.translate.goog/simpler-powershell-host-zum-ausfuehren-von-powershell-skripten-ohne-stoerendes-konsolenfenster/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp --> There is one typo, `Collection <psobject>` should be `Collection <PSObject>`.

Comment: Does not fully answer your question but might do what you need: What about starting once by system startup and keep it in the background so there is no new process? `start-sleep` until it should change the background. Like any tray app would do it.

Comment: @zett42: I've tried creating a custom PowerShell host using a C# script compiled as a Windows application using https://www-mariotti-de.translate.goog/simpler-powershell-host-zum-ausfuehren-von-powershell-skripten-ohne-stoerendes-konsolenfenster/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp
But sadly it still has the same Problem. At manual execution, there is no Window. At automatic Execution, a Windows is throwing me out of the Game.

Comment: Is there perhaps something in Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1 which might be causing the loss of focus to your game? Have you tried running some simple test script which does nothing to see if there is any different behavior?

Comment: @An-dir: I really don't want to have powershell.exe running constantly in the Background as a Service. It takes up resources and it could be unreliable.

Comment: @garbb: no i didn't try this. Will try it tomorrow. But i Posted the Skript. And since there is no Windows upon manual execution, i very much doubt it.

Comment: also this line is weird `1..100 | ForEach-Object { rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters }` it seems to be running the `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` function 100 times? Why do you need to do this? Isn't running it once enough? I tested this on my computer and it seems to hang the window for a second so maybe this is a problem?

Comment: @garbb: The Skript is very much a WIP. But you are right, this is not needed. i Removed 1..100 | ForEach-Object { } and only left rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters. The Skript ist working exactly like before BUT this is and never wars the Problem. I Still get the Windows Popping up.

Comment: What kind of window actually pops up? Is it a PowerShell console or something else?

Comment: @zett42: its so fast that i cant really see it. But i'm pretty sure it's a Windows Terminal Windows thats popping up.

Comment: Have you actually entered the path of PowerShellHost.exe in the scheduled task settings or are you calling it through another script? This should be crucial to avoid the popup window. PowerShellHost.exe should be the program to launch and the path to the PowerShell script should be passed as an argument.

Comment: @zett42: I did it exactly as you described. I Entered the Full Path to the PowerShellHost.exe as Program in Tash Sheduler, and the Argument is the Full Path to the .ps1 Powershell Skript and that's it. Avoiding the Popup is not working upon automitc task sheduler execution.

Comment: @Everyone: You can reproduce that behavior with my provided code and creating an sheduled task as described in my post(s). Then Reboot, Log-in, Run a Exclusiv fullscreen Game and let it sit there until the task gets executed automatically. You'll notice that the game will minimize on every automatic execution. Even using the Compiled PowerShellHost.exe or other Compiled Windowsless/Hidden Console Hosts or forwarders or the aforementioned VB Script.

Comment: I'm currently don't have time to try and reproduce this. You may find this little PowerShell script, that logs all window openings, useful for further debugging. This should be run in the background.
 https://gist.github.com/zett42/b5407343d04d571f802a1ca76496d61d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254153/discussion-between-hige-mynx-and-zett42).

Comment: Please note that `SystemParametersInfo` has been superseded by `IDesktopWallpaper`, but I'm not sure if that's contributing to any issues you're having. You may be interested in trying my [WallP.exe](https://lesferch.github.io/WallP) multi-monitor wallpaper changer. It uses IDesktopWallpaper for Windows 8 and above and SystemParametersInfo only for Windows 7.

Comment: @LesFerch: can you elaborate on that? Saddly, Microsoft isn't Publishing very much examples on how to actually use it. Can you Provide one or some examples?

Comment: How to use `IDesktopWallpaper`? You can look at the [source code for WallP.exe](https://github.com/LesFerch/WallP/blob/main/Program.cs), but why not just run WallP.exe from your PowerShell script? Then your script only has to deal with the image selection part of the logic.

Comment: @LesFerch: this looks to comlicated for me, and it is not Powershell code :/
But i've read that IDesktopWallpaper would set different Wallpaper on each Monitor according to it's resolution?
Since i explicitly wanted to set the same Wallpaper to all Monitors regardless of its resolution i'm finde with using the Win7 Methode. It also Works on thje Latest Build of Windows 11 non Insider so its okay. I would love to use the most modern way but i need detailed examples in powershell code on who to set the dame wallpaper on all monitors using IDesktopWallpaper.

Comment: If you were to use ` IDesktopWallpaper` in PowerShell, it would be C# code embedded in your script. Therefore, it makes more sense to write the entire program in C#. However, a good alternative is to write the script in VBScript or JScript and call WallP.exe from that script. It will be short and simple and eliminate the console window issue you're having. I'll put together an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: Since you have an answer, I'll just post an update here. If you now download [WallP](https://lesferch.github.io/WallP), you'll find that the package now includes a script named `WallpaperSwitcher.vbs`. Just run the script (put a shortcut to it in your Startup folder if desired) to have your wallpaper change every 30 minutes (or whatever value you set for `Interval` in the script). It does a proper shuffle of the files (not just random) of whatever folder you choose (edit the path in the script). You can add or remove files from the folder while the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my Error. There was a second Task in the Task Schedulers Root Folder with my very first test method, directly calling `powershell.exe` with the argument `-File *.ps1`.

I'll now Describe my most Streamlined method to successfully switch the Wallpaper using the same Picture on all Monitors with Powershell and Task Scheduler. You may need to change the Paths and that should be it. This Method works entirely without Admin Rights or elevated access. This method will work on Win7 and newer including the latest non-insider Build of Windows 11.

First you'll need the Powershel Skript which contains the Wallpaper Switching Logic.

###### Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1:

```
# Path of my slideshow
$wallpaper_path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyPictures") + "\Wallpaper\Slide"
# Select random File from path
$new_wallpaper_file_obj = Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaper_path | Get-Random
$new_wallpaper_file_path = $new_wallpaper_file_obj.DirectoryName + "\" + $new_wallpaper_file_obj.Name

# Get currently set Wallpaper File
$TIC = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' TranscodedImageCache -ErrorAction Stop).TranscodedImageCache
$current_wallpaper_file_path = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($TIC) -replace '(.+)([A-Z]:[0-9a-zA-Z\\])+', '$2'

# Check if New Wallpaper isn't the same as the current one, Repeat Random Until this Condition is met.
while ($current_wallpaper_file_path -eq $new_wallpaper_file_path) {
    $new_wallpaper_file_obj = Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaper_path | Get-Random
    $new_wallpaper_file_path = $new_wallpaper_file_obj.DirectoryName + "\" + $new_wallpaper_file_obj.Name
}

# Define New Wallpaper Type to set new Wallpaper with
$setwallpapersrc = @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Wallpaper
{
    public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
    public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
    public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
    public static void SetWallpaper(string path)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange);
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $setwallpapersrc

# Set New Wallpaper
[Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($new_wallpaper_file_path)
```

Alternativly you can use this Code to Set the Next Index as Wallpaper (Terminal Sort Alpheticaly) insead of Random:

###### Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1:

```
# Path of my slideshow
$wallpaper_path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyPictures") + "\Wallpaper\Slide"

# Get currently set Wallpaper File
$TIC = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' TranscodedImageCache -ErrorAction Stop).TranscodedImageCache
$current_wallpaper_file_path = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($TIC) -replace '(.+)([A-Z]:[0-9a-zA-Z\\])+', '$2'
$current_wallpaper_file = Split-Path $current_wallpaper_file_path -leaf

# Get List of Files in Folder
$List = Get-ChildItem -Path $wallpaper_path

# Get Index of Currently Set Wallpaper
$CurrentIndex = 0..($List.Count - 1) | Where-Object { $List.Name[$_] -eq $current_wallpaper_file }

if ($CurrentIndex + 1 -gt $List.Count - 1) {
    # Gett Full Path of Index 0
    $NextWallpaper = $List[0].FullName
}
else {
    # Get Full Path and Name of the Next Index
    $NextWallpaper = $List[$CurrentIndex + 1].FullName
}

# Define New Wallpaper Type to set new Wallpaper with
$setwallpapersrc = @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Wallpaper
{
    public const int SetDesktopWallpaper = 20;
    public const int UpdateIniFile = 0x01;
    public const int SendWinIniChange = 0x02;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
    public static void SetWallpaper(string path)
    {
        SystemParametersInfo(SetDesktopWallpaper, 0, path, UpdateIniFile | SendWinIniChange);
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $setwallpapersrc

# Set Next Wallpaper
[Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($NextWallpaper)
```

Then you need to create a hidden self-containing `*.exe` wrapper for the Skript using the method described here.
https://adamtheautomator.com/ps1-to-exe/#IExpress_20
You can save this Text to `Wallpaper_Slideshow.SED` and save it on your PC.
This File then can be used to Import in `iexpress` to provide some sort of Default Values or (with matching Paths) to create the `*.exe` directly again, say if you changed the `*.ps1` Skript but nothing else and you need a new `*.exe` version because of that.

###### Wallpaper_Slideshow.SED:

```
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=1
HideExtractAnimation=1
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
TargetName=C:\Git\Scripte\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.exe
FriendlyName=Wallpaper Slideshow
AppLaunched=powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Git\Scripte\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
```

Although this guide explicitly wants you to call `iexpress` with Admin right, I never used or tested it with Admin Rights and it's working perfectly fine without Admin Rights. Just call `iexpress`.
Change all Paths as needed in the `*.SED` File, import it and create your `*.exe` File is my preferred way.

Next, you'll need to create a Scheduled Task that'll run the `*.exe` File whenever you want. My example will execute on User's Logon and every 30 Minutes after that indefinitely.
So here is my Exported Task as a `*.xml` File

###### Wallpaper_Slideshow.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2023-06-16T15:28:33.3784615</Date>
    <Author>AzureAD\vanThielMarvin(Group</Author>
    <URI>\Eigene\Wallpaper_Slideshow</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT30M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>AzureAD\vanThielMarvin(Group</UserId>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-12-1-2062191229-1189786572-1918774432-1595217145</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Git\Scripte\Powershell\Wallpaper_Slideshow\Wallpaper_Slideshow.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Then again change all the Paths including the URI.
The URI is the Path in Task Scheduler where you store the Task.
So open Task Scheduler and Create your Folders / Subfolders where you want to Organize your Tasks matching with the URI in the `*.xml`. In Task Scheduler then just click Import Task and select the `*.xml` File. You can now Visually check if all paths are okay. Hit okay to complete the Import process. You can now Reboot your System and everything should work as intended.